# Python urllib2.Request.get_header documentation?

Tags: python, http-headers, urllib2

I'm working on a library that involves pre-processing of urllib2.Request instances (using the urllib2.BaseHandler.xxx_request callbacks). Some of the pre-processors need to examine the headers contained in the supplied urllib2.Request instance.

I noticed the official Python documentation only lists methods for adding a header and for checking if a header exists. There is an undocumented urllib2.Request.get_header method, though it seems to have some quirks. For example, it changes the case of multi-word headers:

```
from urllib2 import Request
req = Request('http://www.example.com')
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

req.get_header('Content-Type') # Produces nothing
req.get_header('Content-type') # Produces 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Is get_header officially supported and/or documented anywhere? If not, is there a best practice for reading header values from a urllib2.Request instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure `get_header` is officially supported, but I can't find it mentioned in the documentation.

As to your "get_header returning None" problem, looking at the source to urllib2.py, the `add_header` method is calling `key.capitalize()` before saving the header key-value pair, which is why `get_header('Content-type')` works and the other variants do not:

```
class Request:
    def add_header(self, key, val):
        self.headers[key.capitalize()] = val

>>> 'content-type'.capitalize()
'Content-type'
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. Strange that the case is modified as header names are case-insensitive.

Comment: Agree, I expected to see either key.lower() or normalizing to caps form `Content-Type` (to match the HTTP RFC), but key.capitalize() was sort of surprising.